# change the background-position of the image only without affecting to css3 gradient

Tags: css

```
.save-btn{
            width: 76px; 
            height: 25px;
            /*background: url(button-icon-sprite.png) no-repeat left top, #b7e7fa; /* Old browsers */
            background-image: url(button-icon-sprite.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b7e7fa 0%, #83c2dc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background-image: url(button-icon-sprite.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b7e7fa), color-stop(100%,#83c2dc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background-image: url(button-icon-sprite.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b7e7fa 0%,#83c2dc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background-image: url(button-icon-sprite.png), -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b7e7fa 0%,#83c2dc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background-image: url(button-icon-sprite.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b7e7fa 0%,#83c2dc 100%);/* IE10+ */
            background-image: url(button-icon-sprite.png), linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b7e7fa 0%,#83c2dc 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b7e7fa', endColorstr='#83c2dc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            background-position: left 10px; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

I am using css3 gradient and a sprite image. I need to change the image position. But when I am changing the background-position, it is affecting to the css3 gradient also. how to solve this

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate the positions using a `,`

```
background-position: left 10px, center center;
                      ^    ^       ^     ^
                      X    Y       X     Y
                        URL        Gradient
```

Am using `center center` for gradient, you can set the position for gradient accordingly, as [@Bolt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538254/1542290) told you to use `0`

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the position for the gradient as well. Resetting it to `0px 0px` should do it:

```
background-position: left 10px, 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this:

```
    background: url(button-icon-sprite.png) left 10px,
                -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b7e7fa 0%, #83c2dc 100%);
```